# Limiting Server request in a page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, httpwebrequest

I think every one goes through this problem. In my page, I use jQuery , jQuery UI, and many plugins and normally all of these plugins including UI, has its own seperate CSS. Furthermore, I have a habit of seperating my CSS as per the module in different files.

So, now whenever I am loading a page, it requests the server for at least 30 additional resources comprising of `styles` and `scripts`, not forgetting `includes` and `requires` of the PHP. In slower PCs (by this I am saying systems with 1GB Ram, which should be more than enough I think) I find my pages slow even in local server.

Now this is really unacceptable, And I need serious suggestion about fixing this issue.

Comment: Just saying: 1GB Ram is nothing these days.

Comment: Are you testing with browser caching disabled?

Comment: @thirtydot, saying `nothing` might be a little harsh, but I agree. @AJ, no, browser caching is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If the website is slow for end users, then you need to figure out exactly why.

- You can measure how long your server-side stuff is taking to execute - that could be a bottleneck.
- The overall latency to your server could be another bottleneck.
- You can measure how long your client-side stuff is taking to execute - that could easily be a bottleneck if you're noticing reduced performance on the client.

Trim down the amount of unecessary Javascript and that kind of thing that you're including. If you're noticing performance drops on the client then it could well be Javascript causing the problem. Do you need the entire JQuery library? Do you use all of it? What about the plugins?

How is your server configured? Are you using caching for PHP?

Can you consolidate your CSS from loads of files into one? Do you need all of it?

You should also look into your use of require and `include` as they can affect performance.

Comment: The plugins, and css used in a page and selected very intensely through a manager, so unnecessary request are not made. The only problem in there are too many of these request. Do you know of any tool that can be used to measure all those things you are saying?

Comment: Client-side, most of the web browsers have debugging tools that will allow you to set breakpoints and measure latency for each request. You can also step through your Javascript and that kind of thing. Internet Explorer has developer tools (press F12), Firefox & Chrome have loads including Firebug which is quite popular for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Most definitely. There is always a balance between being performant and being modular for development. The ideal xhtml to deliver to the client would likely contain a single combined and minified version of your css resources and the same for your js resources, but working with this in development would be aweful.

What I do to combat this is use a script that runs on the deployment servers during a restart operation that does xpath queries to find all the css references in my view templates. It then knows where to locate them on the server, finds them, combines then into one, minifies them and saves a single combined file on the filesystem. Then the script rewrites the view template to only reference this single resource. This is nice because you don't have to think about it in development but you still get performance at deployment time. I still haven't solved the issue of unused css references ....

One thing you can look at is mod_pagespeed:

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html

Comment: So, you are suggesting, I grab the list of all scripts and css and then combine them into a single resource using php(or similar) and then save them in a place and finally use them. Is the saving in the place really necessary, because if it is about creating an all-in-one script or all-in-one css, that is not what I am exactly doing, the scripts and css are very specifically selected for a particular model and then only included. What happens if I dont save them, but combine them on every refresh and load them temporarily?

Comment: Can you also tell me a bit about `xpath queries` I dont quite understand.

Comment: oh sorry. that probably was confusing. i just use xpath queries as an easy way to find all the link elements and script elements inside the head of a document. then i read the href attribute of the link elements and the src attribute of the script elements. These point me to all the scripts being referenced so i can locate them on the filesystem to combine them.

Comment: @Starx -- it consumes some significant resources to do the operation i described and typically you want to cache static resources so that they are served lightning fast. You wouldn't want to be doing this one every page request. These resources never change from one deployment to another so it makes the most sense to do it when you are deploying new code and then to save the combined/minified resources on the filesystem (i make a gzip copy as well).

Comment: Some general info on xpath if you're not familiar at all: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up different things: `includes` and `requires` don´t lead to additional requests and don´t noticeably slow down your pages.

Apart from that, are your pages slow (too much javascript perhaps?) or do they load slow (too many requests?). In case of the second, the first thing to do is combine different css and js files in one css and one js file.

Comment: Well, Yes, the case is the second one. And jeoroen, Are you suggesting that I merge jquery library and say a carousel plugin into one and use them. I dont think that would be so wise. Can you enlighten me a bit more?

Comment: @Starx As far as the css goes, you can combine them easily. About the js, that depends where you load them from; if you load them from your own server, I would combine them, but if you load jquery from for example Google, I would leave it separate to take advantage of already cached files on the visitor's computer.

Comment: So, what would be the best way, to combine such resources?

Comment: @Starx There are several options, like for example Minify: http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Answer (score 0):

Try GZIP compression for CSS and JS. You just need few htaccess files and it compresses all the css and js throughout the website when it loads in the browser.

Comment: I will surely check this out. But still, what are the limitations of using compression?

Comment: What kind of limitations are you concerned of?

Comment: Something like, what are the performance concerns of using GZIP Compression.